# Unable to get navigation bar to display vertically

Tags: css

The problem  is  despite my efforts the menu isn't altering itself into a vertical menu at 320px.  However, despite these attempts I haven't been able to figure out why or where this issue is occurring. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/083e9nz4/9/) with the css and html code where you'll see that the text is wrapping around as suppose to layering itself vertically.

Also, on a side note let me know if anything is not working or if something is unclear in the text as dyslexia can do that sometimes.

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #604E9F;
}
nav li {
    float: left;
}
nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: White;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav li a:hover {
    background-color: #4E4083;
}
nav .clearfix {
    overflow: auto;
}
@media (max-width 320px) {
    .col-12 {
        display: block;
    }
    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #604E9F;
    }
    nav li {
        float: left;
    }
    nav li a {
        display: block;
        color: White;
        text-align: left;
        padding: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav li a:hover {
        background-color: #4E4083;
    }
    nav .clearfix {
        overflow: auto;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just go with a flexbox approach, this is made preciselly for stuff like this.

Comment: @cimmanon Thanks, for the input. I think I knocked it down to the minimal amount of code and the JSFiddle has been updated to reflect that.

Comment: @damianocelent never heard of the flexbox approach will do some research then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    nav li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, I have update your JS fiddle, but not fully styled, it does not get any easier than this.

```
@media screen and (min-width : 280px)  {


nav ul {
transition:1s;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
-ms-flex-direction: column;
flex-direction: column;
```

This is the most important part of the code.

Here the link

https://jsfiddle.net/083e9nz4/16/